# how do unserialize a query serialized form in symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

i'm trying to unserialize my serialized form from ajax to my symfony controller,so i used $('#formID').serialize()

```
<form id="form_insert">
    <input type="text" name="data[id]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[users]" />
</form>
```

it works for  one user but i need to insert many users like this:

```
<form id="form_insert">
    <input type="text" name="data[id]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[users]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[users]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[users]" />
</form>
```

my query seems fine:

```
data%users%5D=vinccent&data%users%5D=sebas&data%users%5D=mathieu&data%5Bid%5D=1
```

after unserilized:
what i get:

```
array (size=1)
  'data' => 
    array (size=28)
      'users' => string 'mathieu' (length=4) //last user ready inserted
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

what i need:

```
array (size=1)
  'data' => 
    array (size=28)
      'users' => 
           array => (size=2) 
              'vinccent' (length=8)
              'sebas'(length=5)
              'mathieu' (length=7) 
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: How are you unserializing the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered similar issue before, though I don't know it's the same or not, but I would write this to get array of form data:

```
<form id="form_insert">
    <input type="text" name="data[id]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[users][]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[users][]" />
    <input type="text" name="data[users][]" />
</form>
```

it's seems the users value of the form was assigned to the last data[users] which is `mathieu`